# Remove a sentence from a paragraph that has a specific pattern with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a large number of descriptions that can be anywhere from 5 to 20 sentences each.  I am trying to put a script together that will locate and remove a sentence that contains a word with numbers before or after it.

before example:  Hello world.  Todays department has 345 employees.  Have a good day.
after example:  Hello world.  Have a good day.

My main problem right now is identifying the violation.
Here "345 employees" is what causes the sentence to be removed.  However, each description will have a different number and possibly a different variation of the word employee.
I would like to avoid having to create a table of all the different variations of employee.

JTB

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "different variations of employee".

Comment: Will this be the *only* occurrence of a number in the text? Will it be correct to locate the number, and then remove all text preceding it (back to the previous `.` or the start of the string), and all text succeeding it (up to the next `.` or the end of the string)?

Comment: Does it have to be one of a specific set of words or any word that is preceded by numbers?

Comment: Conrad---Different variations of employee can be employee, employment, employees, employed, ect.... 

Damien---It will not be the only occurrence of a number in the text. 

Asad---It can not be any word pro/preceding numbers. The word must have a variation of employee with a number preceding or proceding it.

Comment: Would it be possible to use regular expressions some how?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would make a good SQL Puzzle.

**Disclaimer: there are probably TONS of edge cases that would blow this up**

This would take a string, split it out into a table with a row for each sentence, then remove the rows that matched a condition, and then finally join them all back into a string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_SplitRemoveJoin(@Val VARCHAR(2000), @FilterCond VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tbl TABLE (rid INT IDENTITY(1,1), val VARCHAR(2000))
    DECLARE @t VARCHAR(2000)

    -- Split into table @tbl
    WHILE CHARINDEX('.',@Val) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @t = LEFT(@Val, CHARINDEX('.', @Val))
        INSERT @tbl (val) VALUES (@t)
        SET @Val = RIGHT(@Val, LEN(@Val) - LEN(@t))
    END

    IF (LEN(@Val) > 0)
        INSERT @tbl VALUES (@Val)


    -- Filter out condition 
    DELETE FROM @tbl WHERE val LIKE @FilterCond

    -- Join back into 1 string
    DECLARE @i INT, @rv VARCHAR(2000)
    SET @i = 1
    WHILE @i <= (SELECT MAX(rid) FROM @tbl)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @rv = IsNull(@rv,'') + IsNull(val,'') FROM @tbl WHERE rid = @i
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
    RETURN @rv

END
go


CREATE TABLE #TMP (rid INT IDENTITY(1,1), sentence VARCHAR(2000))
INSERT #tmp (sentence) VALUES ('Hello world. Todays department has 345 employees. Have a good day.')
INSERT #tmp (sentence) VALUES ('Hello world. Todays department has 15 emps. Have a good day. Oh and by the way there are 12 employees somewhere else')


SELECT 
    rid, sentence, dbo.fn_SplitRemoveJoin(sentence, '%[0-9] Emp%')
FROM #tmp t
```

returns

```
rid | sentence |  |
1 | Hello world. Todays department has 345 employees. Have a good day. | Hello world. Have a good day.|
2 | Hello world. Todays department has 15 emps. Have a good day. Oh and by the way there are 12 employees somewhere else | Hello world. Have a good day. |
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used the split/remove/join technique as well.

The main points are:

- This uses a pair of [recursive CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), rather than a UDF.
- This will work with all English sentence endings: `.` or `!` or `?`
- This removes whitespace to make the comparison for "digit then employee" so you don't have to worry about multiple spaces and such.

Here's the [SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffe60/1), and the code:

```
-- Split descriptions into sentences (could use period, exclamation point, or question mark)
-- Delete any sentences that, without whitespace, are like '%[0-9]employ%'
-- Join sentences back into descriptions
;with Splitter as (
    select ID
        , ltrim(rtrim(Data)) as Data
        , cast(null as varchar(max)) as Sentence
        , 0 as SentenceNumber
    from Descriptions -- Your table here
    union all
    select ID
        , case when Data like '%[.!?]%' then right(Data, len(Data) - patindex('%[.!?]%', Data)) else null end
        , case when Data like '%[.!?]%' then left(Data, patindex('%[.!?]%', Data)) else Data end
        , SentenceNumber + 1
    from Splitter
    where Data is not null
), Joiner as (
    select ID
        , cast('' as varchar(max)) as Data
        , 0 as SentenceNumber
    from Splitter
    group by ID
    union all
    select j.ID
        , j.Data +
            -- Don't want "digit+employ" sentences, remove whitespace to search
            case when replace(replace(replace(replace(s.Sentence, char(9), ''), char(10), ''), char(13), ''), char(32), '') like '%[0-9]employ%' then '' else s.Sentence end
        , s.SentenceNumber
    from Joiner j
        join Splitter s on j.ID = s.ID and s.SentenceNumber = j.SentenceNumber + 1
)
-- Final Select
select a.ID, a.Data
from Joiner a
    join (
        -- Only get max SentenceNumber
        select ID, max(SentenceNumber) as SentenceNumber
        from Joiner
        group by ID
    ) b on a.ID = b.ID and a.SentenceNumber = b.SentenceNumber
order by a.ID, a.SentenceNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this. Please note that it only works if you have one number in all sentences.

```
declare @d VARCHAR(1000) = 'Hello world. Todays department has 345 employees. Have a good day.'
declare @dr VARCHAR(1000)

set @dr = REVERSE(@d)

SELECT   REVERSE(RIGHT(@dr,LEN(@dr) - CHARINDEX('.',@dr,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@dr))))

 + RIGHT(@d,LEN(@d) - CHARINDEX('.',@d,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@d)) + 1)
```